# IDS cookie always expires in 24 hours?

Tags: identityserver3

I'm setting up IDS and I have the following in my Startup.cs file in my host project:

```html
    idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
    {
     SiteName = "My SSO",
     SigningCertificate = LoadSigningCertificate(),
     AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
     {
      EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect = true,
      CookieOptions = new CookieOptions
      {
       AllowRememberMe = false,
       IsPersistent = true,
       SlidingExpiration = true,
       ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(14, 0, 0, 0)
      },
      EnableSignOutPrompt = false
     },
     EventsOptions = new EventsOptions
     {
      RaiseErrorEvents = true,
      RaiseFailureEvents = true,
      RaiseInformationEvents = true,
      RaiseSuccessEvents = true
     },
     Factory = factory
    });
```

As I understand it the CookieOptions set to :

IsPersistent = true, SlidingExpiration = true, ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(14, 0, 0, 0)

should keep a cookie for the IDS that auto-logs in the user after they have initially logged in for a period of two weeks with a sliding window. This does not happen. The user is logged out of the application after 24 hours and is required to reenter their credentials on the IDS login page.

I also see that there are a ton of nonce cookies for the application... this is very odd. Sometimes it says request too long - I think this is related.

Please help.

Comment: Is the user doing single sign-out? That would remove the cookie from IdSvr.

Comment: No sign out has been performed by the user.

Comment: You might just be dropping/losing cookies. If you have too many cookies at your host, then the browser will just stop keeping track of them. It's ~4K per host, IIRC.

Comment: Is there some problem with the middleware that causes cookies to stack up? I recall hearing something about this and I think it might be affecting me.

Comment: @BrockAllen did you see my previous comment? https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2518 https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1407
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1124